Adaptec USBXchange USB to SCSI adapter on Windows 11
I have an Adaptec USBXchange USB to SCSI adapter that works up to Windows XP, but there are no newer drivers.
I reverse-engineered the Windows 98 driver by capturing the USB packets as after it is inserted. It uses a Cypress low cost microcontroller that requires the firmware to be loaded into its RAM by the driver. It then resets and re-enumerates on the USB bus. I created a small Windows app that replicates the firmware upload, and the device now appears as an "Adaptec USBXchange Adapter" device in Device Manger.
However, there is still no driver for it. I thought this would make it work, as I found a mailing list post where the author of the Linux driver claims that after loading the firmware it acts as a standard USB Mass Storage device.
Mine appears to be a mass storage device, but the USB Interface Descriptor has the bInterfaceClass set to 0xFF, which is invalid. I tried changing it to 0x08 (mass storage) and setting the subclass to 0x06 (SCSI pass-through) which made Windows load the Mass Storage driver for it, but after several seconds the driver reports an error due to it not being the standard protocol.
Perhaps mine is a different version to the one that the Linux driver works with. Unfortunately I have not been able to contact the author of that driver to ask about it.
I believe that despite the USB string, this is actually a USB2Xchange device, as that's the driver it uses.
Is any more information on this device available? Does anyone have the complete Linux driver source code? Every copy online seems to have gone.
